# How to query a customize key in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Considering this tables: `person` and `employee` to which connected to person by `person_id`. This `person_id` is also the Primary & Foreign key of `employee` table. Thus in my migrations, i have this:

```
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('person_id');
    $table->foreign('person_id')->references('id')->on('persons')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

and my `show` method is like this one

```
public function show(Employee $employee){
    dd($employee->person_id);
    $employee = Employee::where('person_id', $employee->person_id)->orderBy('employee_number', 'asc')->join('persons', 'employees.person_id', '=', 'persons.id')->first();
    return view('employee.show', compact('employee'));
}
```

But i am experiencing this issue:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `employees` where `id` = 5 limit 1)
```

**Does the query is not aware of the column i am using?**

Comment: `select * from employees where id = 5 limit 1` ?   You sure this PHP code is generating that SQL? As `Employee::where('person_id', $employee->person_id)` does not use the `id` column ...

Comment: Can you run and post the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE employees` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE persons` ?

Comment: I think it's not, because it does not hit the show method.

Comment: ... and the code off `Employee` class also check @Saly3301 's answer as that answer might be right atleast it makes alot of sense ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the primary key in the Employee model

```php
class Employee extends Model
{
    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'person_id';

    public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee', 'person_id', 'person_id');
    }
}
```

Then query using `find`

```php
Employee::find($employee->person_id)->with('person')->first();
```

`orderBy` and `first` are redundant on one result queries

And if you want to return the Employee with the Person, just access the relationship object (employee is returned from route model binding)

```php
public function show(Employee $employee) {
    $person = $employee->person;
    return view('employee.show', compact('employee', 'person'));
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much there are still lot of things i have to explore in this frameworks, and thank for pointing out ```orderBy``` and ```first```.

Comment: You're welcome, please consider accepting the answer if it solves the problem :)

Comment: @AnirudhLou database abstraction frameworks layers makes it a bit harder to see when something is redundant as it is abstracted which SQL it generates ..   in SQL it is more easy to see if id column is unique things like DISTINCT / GROUP BY / ORDER BY / LIMIT can be redundant consider this assume id column to have a `PRIMARY KEY` then .. `SELECT DISTINCT id ...`, `SELECT ... GROUP BY id` (wierd example i know) , ... `SELECT .. WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1`,  `SELECT .. WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` and `SELECT .. WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY id` .. notice it much more easy to see in SQL..

Comment: Using this find, why it only returns my employee? I mean, it does not includes person data?

Comment: You need to eager load the relationship, I updated my answer

Comment: .. also @AnirudhLou be sure not to run into SELECT N + 1 problems which is also very easy ... [What is the “N+1 selects problem” in ORM (Object-Relational Mapping)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping)

Comment: on the other side, that is the ```hasOne``` is it also ```$this->hasOne('App\Employee', 'person_id', 'person_id');``` or ```$this->hasOne('App\Employee', 'person_id', 'id');```?

Comment: second argument is foreign key, third argument is local key